# plot deviance residuals vs fitted values or log(fitted values)

Tags: residuals, poisson-regression, diagnostic

I did a poisson regression by hand and want to create a diagnostic plot. Now iam not sure, should i plot deviance residuals vs fitted  values or vs log(fitted values)?
Why or why not?

Comment: Try it both ways and see which makes more sense to you!

Comment: use https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DHARMa/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Against actual fitted and against the fit on the scale of the linear predictor would both be reasonable -- either should be fine as far as assessing whether the residuals deviate from flatness as the fitted values change.

Which is easier to work with may depend on a number of factors (e.g. how broad a range of predicted values is covered, the pattern of the predictors, personal preference)